# Bash function to do awk math (floating point)

Tags: bash, awk

I want to create a simple bash function that will evaluate the math that I pass it using awk. eg:

```
awkmath()
{
  echo "$1 $3" | awk '{ print($1 "'$2'" $2) }'
}

awkmath '2' '*' '3'  #Prints 6
```

So far I can't get this to work though.  Instead of getting "6" I get "2*3". I know there are other ways to do this. But I'm interested in seeing if someone can make this work.  It seems like a simple thing, but the bash interpreting gets a little nuts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
awkmath()
{
  echo "$1 $3" | awk '{ print $1 '"$2"' $2 }'
}
$ awkmath '2' '*' '3'
6
```

This uses the string delimiters (`"`) in the shell to avoid globbing and word splitting before constructing the awk command:

`'{print $1 '"$2"' $2}'` -> `'{print 2 '"*"' 3}'` -> `'{print 2 * 3}'`

while what you had originally leaves `*` inside string delimiters after constructing the awk coommand:

`'{print $1 "'$2'" $2}'` -> `'{print 2 "'*'" 3}'` -> `'{print 2 "*" 3}'`

and in fact you'd be lucky in that 2nd case if the `*` wasn't expanded into a list of file names in your current directory before the awk command was constructed.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use `bc` instead of awk: your math expression can be arbitrarily complex

```
math() {
  local out=$(bc -l <<< "$*")
  if [[ -z $out ]]; then
    return 1
  else
    echo "$out"
  fi
}

math '(2+3)' \* '(5-sqrt(9))'
```

You do have the pain of protecting characters that are special to the shell